# What is use of formdata in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, javascript-objects

When we console log the formdata, it returns an empty object. I was wondering how it is used to store data in key-value pairs, as it returns an empty object.

I used it in a react js code where i had a function which runs when form is submitted.

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      try {
        const formData = new FormData(e.target);
        console.log("formData", formData);
        //here it gives empty object

        formData.append("access_key", "00000000");
        console.log("formData after append", formData);
        //here also empty object

        const object = Object.fromEntries(formData);
        console.log("formData is made object", object);
        //as soon as we convert it into an object it gives value
}
```

But how?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35337640/519413

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63347427/519413

Comment: We have a mixed question of what FormData is and how the console log works. The console log will JSON output only publicly accessible fields, skipping the methods. FormData has no publicly accessible fields, so the output looks like empty object